# Is there a way to bind to a property of a templated control?

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I want to set the background colour of a ListViewItem to the colour that is used in the DataTemplate of the Item.

This is one of the DataTemplates, note the BackGround colour being set:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:DataPointViewModel}">
    <UniformGrid Columns="2" Background="LimeGreen">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And this is the ItemContainerStyle with the Border in it, set as the ItemContainerStyle of the ListView:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding BackGround}">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I want to avoid to have the Background colour in the ViewModel itself. So far all my efforts just resulted in Binding Errors from Bindings like:

```
{Binding BackGround, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UniformGrid}}
```

With the Binding set to "TemplateBinding BackGround" it does successfully use the colour I set in the Style itself, which is what I would expect.

How do I bind to the BackGround property in the DataTemplate or is this not achievable?

Comment: Isn't your uniformgrid in the datatemplate on top of the listviewitem? Hence on top of the border whose background you are asking to set?

Comment: Yes it is, but it does not fill out the whole Border. The UniformGrid is just an example, some of my other templates use other controls. I want to set the colour in the template and reference it.